# Combing two returned rows in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure, which I've temporarily filled with values that returns the time spent on logged jobs at my company, I've grouped the JobTypeID's that should fit into 4 different Columns, Dev hours worked, Dev hours charged, Support hours worked, and Support hours charged. Upon running the code procedure, due to how I'm using the GroupBy clause it's splitting the data into multiple rows, how can i fix this so it outputs the data into one row?

```
;WITH cte AS (

SELECT
       DATEPART(Year, StartTime) AS YearNumber,
       DATEPART(Month, StartTime) AS MonthNumber,
       DateName(Month, StartTime) + ' ' + CAST(DatePart(Year, StartTime) AS nvarchar(50)) AS TimePeriod,
       DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(Day, 0, StartTime), 0) AS FromDate,
       DateDiff(minute, StartTime, EndTime) AS JobTime,
       tblJobWorkLog.ChargeableTime,
       WorkLogJobTypeID,
       tblJobWorkLog.SystemUserID

FROM
       tblJobWorkLog
       INNER JOIN tblJob ON tblJobWorkLog.JobID = tblJob.JobID
       INNER JOIN tblContact ON tblJob.ContactID = tblContact.ContactID

WHERE
       tblJobWorkLog.StartTime >= '20150511'
       AND tblJobWorkLog.EndTime <= '20150515'
       AND SystemUserID = '65405273-6BFD-4482-8A0D-BC6430AC996D'

)

SELECT
       FromDate,
       Case when WorkLogJobTypeID = 'FA5E6979-D228-44B7-A91B-8DDC8DDC709B' OR WorkLogJobTypeID = '3171B295-60E9-4724-95A3-04FA182D7D43' OR WorkLogJobTypeID = '52c2691f-ff0a-4263-a440-8a309f868f93' then (SUM(JobTime) / 60.0) end as SupportHoursWorked,
       Case when WorkLogJobTypeID = 'FA5E6979-D228-44B7-A91B-8DDC8DDC709B' OR WorkLogJobTypeID = '3171B295-60E9-4724-95A3-04FA182D7D43' OR WorkLogJobTypeID = '52c2691f-ff0a-4263-a440-8a309f868f93' then SUM(ChargeableTime) end AS SupportHoursCharged,
       Case when WorkLogJobTypeID = 'D0E910B1-B4BD-430C-AD04-EB4E67946806' OR WorkLogJobTypeID = 'B0BBF362-294D-4262-BED8-EDA7EE74745B' OR WorkLogJobTypeID = '1E333ADC-E4F2-4042-8B65-E25F2770D59F' OR WorkLogJobTypeID = 'A445B7CE-E9E4-48E6-B5AA-83C83F045315' 
       OR WorkLogJobTypeID = '1D83F510-87FA-446E-9337-3D0376210D57' OR WorkLogJobTypeID = 'B59C1596-E1D0-4118-A805-65208E27AFB5' OR WorkLogJobTypeID = 'F44A4B3C-B149-45A8-A9F0-5A57883482FD' then (SUM(JobTime) / 60.0) end as DevelopmentHoursWorked,
       Case when WorkLogJobTypeID = 'D0E910B1-B4BD-430C-AD04-EB4E67946806' OR WorkLogJobTypeID = 'B0BBF362-294D-4262-BED8-EDA7EE74745B' OR WorkLogJobTypeID = '1E333ADC-E4F2-4042-8B65-E25F2770D59F' OR WorkLogJobTypeID = 'A445B7CE-E9E4-48E6-B5AA-83C83F045315' 
       OR WorkLogJobTypeID = '1D83F510-87FA-446E-9337-3D0376210D57' OR WorkLogJobTypeID = 'B59C1596-E1D0-4118-A805-65208E27AFB5' OR WorkLogJobTypeID = 'F44A4B3C-B149-45A8-A9F0-5A57883482FD' then SUM(ChargeableTime) end as DevelopmentHoursCharged

FROM
       cte

GROUP BY
       FromDate, WorkLogJobTypeID
ORDER BY
       FromDate
```

RESULTS:

```
2015-05-11  NULL        NULL        1.250000    1.250000
2015-05-11  1.166666    0.5         NULL        NULL
2015-05-12  0.000000    0.0         NULL        NULL
2015-05-12  NULL        NULL        3.250000    1.250000
2015-05-12  0.250000    0.000000    NULL        NULL
2015-05-12  NULL        NULL        0.250000    0.000000
2015-05-13  NULL        NULL        0.750000    0.750000
2015-05-13  0.000000    0.000000    NULL        NULL
2015-05-13  NULL        NULL        0.0         0.000000
2015-05-14  NULL        NULL        1.0         1.000000
2015-05-14  4.000000    1.166667    NULL        NULL
2015-05-14  NULL        NULL        1.0         0.750000
```

^ I need to combine the date results into one row

Comment: Use max on the columns with nulls, and group by from date.  However, I don't believe you're going to be able to do that without taking the CTE out and creating subqueries, as I don't believe you're going to be able to nest the CTE in a subquery correctly given the nested group by.  You may be able to do the case logic in the CTe, then the worklogJobTypeId could be excluded from the select from CTE...

Comment: If i remove the GroupBy WorkLogJobTypeID i get the following error: Column 'cte.WorkLogJobTypeID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Please provide the relevant DML and the DDL to create a sample data. While xQbert's suggestion will work, someone might be able to provide a better solution that doesn't involve adding another query on top of what you have right now.

Comment: Well you get multiple rows, because you do a Group by of the FromDate. It is going to group all the rows with the same date and workLogjobTypeId

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies this didn't work first time round, You can use the following which should now give you the result you're looking for:

```
WITH cte AS (

SELECT
       DATEPART(Year, StartTime) AS YearNumber,
       DATEPART(Month, StartTime) AS MonthNumber,
       DateName(Month, StartTime) + ' ' + CAST(DatePart(Year, StartTime) AS nvarchar(50)) AS TimePeriod,
       DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(Day, 0, StartTime), 0) AS FromDate,
       DateDiff(minute, StartTime, EndTime) AS JobTime,
       tblJobWorkLog.ChargeableTime,
       WorkLogJobTypeID,
       tblJobWorkLog.SystemUserID

FROM
       tblJobWorkLog
       INNER JOIN tblJob ON tblJobWorkLog.JobID = tblJob.JobID
       INNER JOIN tblContact ON tblJob.ContactID = tblContact.ContactID

WHERE
       tblJobWorkLog.StartTime >= '20150511'
       AND tblJobWorkLog.EndTime <= '20150515'
       AND SystemUserID = '65405273-6BFD-4482-8A0D-BC6430AC996D'

)

Select FromDate, SUM(SupportHoursWorked) SupportHoursWorked, SUM(SupportHoursCharged) SupportHoursCharged, SUM(DevelopmentHoursWorked) DevelopmentHoursWorked, SUM(DevelopmentHoursCharged) DevelopmentHoursCharged

From

(SELECT
       FromDate,
       Case when WorkLogJobTypeID = 'FA5E6979-D228-44B7-A91B-8DDC8DDC709B' OR WorkLogJobTypeID = '3171B295-60E9-4724-95A3-04FA182D7D43' OR WorkLogJobTypeID = '52c2691f-ff0a-4263-a440-8a309f868f93' then (SUM(JobTime) / 60.0) end as SupportHoursWorked,
       Case when WorkLogJobTypeID = 'FA5E6979-D228-44B7-A91B-8DDC8DDC709B' OR WorkLogJobTypeID = '3171B295-60E9-4724-95A3-04FA182D7D43' OR WorkLogJobTypeID = '52c2691f-ff0a-4263-a440-8a309f868f93' then SUM(ChargeableTime) end AS SupportHoursCharged,
       Case when WorkLogJobTypeID = 'D0E910B1-B4BD-430C-AD04-EB4E67946806' OR WorkLogJobTypeID = 'B0BBF362-294D-4262-BED8-EDA7EE74745B' OR WorkLogJobTypeID = '1E333ADC-E4F2-4042-8B65-E25F2770D59F' OR WorkLogJobTypeID = 'A445B7CE-E9E4-48E6-B5AA-83C83F045315' 
       OR WorkLogJobTypeID = '1D83F510-87FA-446E-9337-3D0376210D57' OR WorkLogJobTypeID = 'B59C1596-E1D0-4118-A805-65208E27AFB5' OR WorkLogJobTypeID = 'F44A4B3C-B149-45A8-A9F0-5A57883482FD' then (SUM(JobTime) / 60.0) end as DevelopmentHoursWorked,
       Case when WorkLogJobTypeID = 'D0E910B1-B4BD-430C-AD04-EB4E67946806' OR WorkLogJobTypeID = 'B0BBF362-294D-4262-BED8-EDA7EE74745B' OR WorkLogJobTypeID = '1E333ADC-E4F2-4042-8B65-E25F2770D59F' OR WorkLogJobTypeID = 'A445B7CE-E9E4-48E6-B5AA-83C83F045315' 
       OR WorkLogJobTypeID = '1D83F510-87FA-446E-9337-3D0376210D57' OR WorkLogJobTypeID = 'B59C1596-E1D0-4118-A805-65208E27AFB5' OR WorkLogJobTypeID = 'F44A4B3C-B149-45A8-A9F0-5A57883482FD' then SUM(ChargeableTime) end as DevelopmentHoursCharged

FROM
       cte

GROUP BY
       FromDate, WorkLogJobTypeID) a
       Group by FromDate

ORDER BY
       FromDate
```

Answer (score 0):

Use sum on the columns with nulls, or you will lose results, then group by date

Comment: Edit your post to include an example of this please.

Answer (score 0):

This should work and be more readable:

```
;WITH cte AS (

SELECT
  DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(Day, 0, StartTime), 0) AS FromDate,
  DateDiff(minute, StartTime, EndTime) AS JobTime,
  tblJobWorkLog.ChargeableTime,
  CASE WHEN WorkLogJobTypeID in 
  ('FA5E6979-D228-44B7-A91B-8DDC8DDC709B', '3171B295-60E9-4724-95A3-04FA182D7D43', 
   '52c2691f-ff0a-4263-a440-8a309f868f93') THEN 1 END chk1,
  CASE WHEN WorkLogJobTypeID in 
    ('D0E910B1-B4BD-430C-AD04-EB4E67946806', 'B0BBF362-294D-4262-BED8-EDA7EE74745B', 
     '1E333ADC-E4F2-4042-8B65-E25F2770D59F', 'A445B7CE-E9E4-48E6-B5AA-83C83F045315', 
     '1D83F510-87FA-446E-9337-3D0376210D57', 'B59C1596-E1D0-4118-A805-65208E27AFB5', 
     'F44A4B3C-B149-45A8-A9F0-5A57883482FD') THEN 1 END chk2
FROM
       tblJobWorkLog
       INNER JOIN tblJob ON tblJobWorkLog.JobID = tblJob.JobID
       INNER JOIN tblContact ON tblJob.ContactID = tblContact.ContactID
WHERE
       tblJobWorkLog.StartTime >= '20150511'
       AND tblJobWorkLog.EndTime <= '20150515'
       AND SystemUserID = '65405273-6BFD-4482-8A0D-BC6430AC996D'
)
SELECT
       FromDate,
       SUM(chk1 * JobTime) / 60.0 as SupportHoursWorked,
       SUM(chk1 * ChargeableTime) AS SupportHoursCharged,
       SUM(chk2 * JobTime) / 60.0 as DevelopmentHoursWorked,
       SUM(chk2 * ChargeableTime) as DevelopmentHoursCharged
FROM
       cte
GROUP BY FromDate
ORDER BY FromDate
```